# JQuery - OnKeyPress Input Text Title Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, case, title

Is there a way to make text inside of input text box to title case each time user pressing their keyboard using a jQuery? example:

johny english

to

Johny English

Here's the input text box

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure CSS by applying **[text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)** property:

> The text-transform CSS property specifies how to capitalize an
>   element's text. It can be used to make text appear in all-uppercase or
>   all-lowercase, or with each word capitalized.

```
#fullname {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LW9yM/1/)**

Comment: Thx! Appreciate the simple solution given!

Comment: But doesn't this just make it look like the input is capitalized. When the form is submitted it send the original value. Why is this a correct answer?

Comment: Won't work if all the input is capitalized, since it will ignore all the characters except the first one of each word. (unfortunately....)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GH3Lj/

Here you are with css `text-transform : capitalize` for the purpose.

Comment: Woah, what a simple solution. And here I'm trying to find the hard way by using jQuery. Thx!